# Change view from SKScene to a ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, xcode9, arkit

I am making a game using ARKit. Im having trouble witching to the ARSCNview from a SKSecene.

I have this so far:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

//Back button
let backToBrand = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Electric Boots")

class Lamborghini: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        //Background
        let menuBackground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")
        menuBackground.setScale(1)
        menuBackground.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: 

self.size.height/2)
    menuBackground.zPosition = 0
    self.addChild(menuBackground)

    //Back button
    backToBrand.text = "Back"
    backToBrand.fontSize = 50
    backToBrand.fontColor = SKColor.white
    backToBrand.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.left
    backToBrand.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width*0.05, y: self.size.height*0.67)
    backToBrand.zPosition = 1
    self.addChild(backToBrand)

    //Test button
    let test = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Electric Boots")
    test.text = "test AR"
    test.fontSize = 100
    test.fontColor = SKColor.white
    test.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
    test.zPosition = 2
    test.name = "test"
    self.addChild(test)
}
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let pointOfTouch = touch.location(in: self)
        let nodeITapped = atPoint(pointOfTouch)

        if nodeITapped == backToBrand {
            let sceneToMOveTo = BrandMenu(size: self.size)
            sceneToMOveTo.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
            let sceneTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
            self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMOveTo, transition: sceneTransition)

        }
        if nodeITapped.name == "test"{
            let sceneToMOveTo = ARView(size: self.size)
            sceneToMOveTo.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
            let sceneTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
            self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMOveTo, transition: sceneTransition)
        }
    }
}
```

The part having the problem is:

```
if nodeITapped.name == "test" {
    let sceneToMOveTo = ARView(size: self.size)
    sceneToMOveTo.scaleMode = self.scaleMode
    let sceneTransition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.5)
    self.view!.presentScene(sceneToMOveTo, transition: sceneTransition)
}
```

The AR scene is in a ViewController within the `Main.Storyboard`.

I can't get the Game Scene to move to the ViewController and move back.

Comment: ARView and BrandMenu are 2 different things.  ARView is not an SKScene, it is a member of UIView (I am guessing).  only scenes can be presented via presentScene. You need to approach your problem differently.

Comment: I’m trying to get the game scene to move to the class containing the ARSCNView so it’s game scene -> view controller. If this changes anything.

Comment: Not sure you want to do that.  You want to get to the AR scene, the view is nothing and chances are you probably want to be using the same view for both the ARScene and the SKScene

Comment: That makes sense. So if I changed the class type to a SKScene it would allow me to programmatically add an ARSCNView?

Comment: you only want one ARSceneView, and you shoudnt need to do it programatically, Your hierarchy should already by ViewController -> View -> Scene.  Now you are claiming you are doing ARKit, but you make no explanation on what technologies you are using.  I would take a step back from coding and just lay out and write down the technologies you plan on using to get what you need done and make a road map for yourself.  When you make the road map,  if you do not see a clear connection between 2 technologies, then chances are, it doesn't exist.

Comment: Well I started making the game as a “Game” when you first start in Xcode. I didn’t use the “AR Game” when starting. All I need to do is have the game scene move to the AR scene when a node is touched. Just like if you touch the node and it moves to another game scene view. But instead it’s displaying the ARSCNView.

Comment: Sorry, what you are saying doesn't make sense because that is not the way you do things.  Nodes should not be change views ever.  Views can swap scenes and view controllers can swap views, nothing else can happen.  Try learning how the hierarchy works and you may find the answer to your problem,   ARKit invokes both Scenekit and SpriteKit technologies (Technically it is all scenekit and it just interacts with spritekit)  so chances are you want to just use the ARScnView to present your SpriteKit scene whenever you need it